# Why do these .NET capture group regular expression (regex) statements function differently?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, capture-group

I'm working with strings that have a bunch of white spaces before the data I want to capture. For some reason,

```
(?:\\s*)(?<1>.+)
```

works, but

```
(?<1>\\S+)
```

does not. The former works exactly how I want it to, but the latter doesn't get any matches. Is matching white 0+ white spaces but not capturing and matching any 1+ any character and capturing not the same as matching and capturing any 1+ non-white-space characters?

Apologies if this is a duplicate; I searched and couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: When I try them, the match the same, could you give us an example of an input string and what the expected match is?

Comment: You cannot expect `.` and `\S`  to match the same chars. These are basic regex constructs, see the reference at the top.